# Tezos node stuck on error (hangzhounet)

Tags: node

my tezos node is stucked on this error:

```
Current head: BLpEPZhSw81k (timestamp: 2022-01-24T03:12:08.000-00:00, validation: 2022-01-24T11:41:02.077-00:00)
Jan 24 12:41:03.343 - protocol_cache: start loading cache now
Jan 24 12:41:04.792 - protocol_cache: stop loading cache now
Error:
  Kind.of_magic: unexpected magic char '\000'
```

It was running properly until this error appears in logs. I've try to restart it and to delete data to start from scratch, but the problem still happens on this head.

Do you know what I can do to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

There are similar issues reported for this error. The main investigation relies here https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/issues/1982

Can you have a look to it? The main conclusion is that there is something strange with EBS snapshot of an EC2 volume. Are you using this kind of architecture?

Comment: Thanks for the link. But I'm not using this kind of architecture. I'm using a personal computer with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: Oh! So this is unexpected. Can you open an issue with as much details as possible on https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/issues/ ?

Comment: Ok. I don't have much details to give, but we will see.

Comment: And I've started from scratch another node on hangzhounet. And now I'm stuck on this error: Error:
  (Invalid_argument "String.blit / Bytes.blit_string")

tezos-node: Error:
              (Invalid_argument "String.blit / Bytes.blit_string")

Comment: Indeed, this is very strange. Please open an issue to allow a better tracking of the problem, and add as much details as possible (machine, hardware, os, …).